# React contextType not getting context values

Tags: reactjs

I have this little example where i'm trying to use `contextType` and i got it all wrong. This is a simple reproduction of what i'm working with.

```
import React from 'react';

const AppContext = React.createContext({ id: 222 });

class ContextProvider extends React.Component {
  props;

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={{id: 1234}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
 }
}


class ContextConsumer extends React.Component {
  props;

  context;

  render() {
    const { id } = this.context;// id is undefined
    console.log(this.context); // logs an empty object {}

    return (
      <div>Hello {id}</div>
    );
  }
}

ContextConsumer.contextType = AppContext;


const ContextApp = ({}) => {
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <ContextConsumer />
    </ContextProvider>
  );
};

export default ContextApp;
```

Can i get any directions why `contextType` doesnt work but if i use `AppContext.Consumer`, everything works alright.

React version: 16.6.3

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I just realized i needed to upgrade react and react-dom to 16.6 in the host application too. This was so quick.